# curl: (52) Empty reply from server - with detailed scenario

Tags: bash, unix, curl

I am need of some insight on this issue. I am using the following curl command and I see some issues.

```
curl -l -U serviceact:servicepwd -v-x sftpproxy:port sftp://user:pwd@vendor.com:port/reports/

* About to connect() to proxy proxy port  (#0)
*   Trying 000.000.0000.00
* Connected to proxy (IP) port (#0)
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'serviceact'
* Server auth using Basic with user 'vendoractusername'
* GET sftp://vendoractusername:pwd@vendorurl:port/reports/ HTTP/1.1
* Proxy-Authorization: Basic ANDKDKmjfkkf
* Authorization: Basic kdkdkkdMMMMM
* User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
* Host: vendorurl:port
* Accept: */*
* Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
*
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host proxy left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I am trying to run this above curl command and I get the following error. What am I doing wrong here.
I tried curl -L and I get the same error. please someone help.

Comment: Try changing your `-v-x` into `-v -x` or `-vx`, I think this might be it

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your response. I am completely new to this. I changed as you said and the error is still same. is there any way to make this request.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your `curl` command, I think you should check for problems on the proxy side. It seems likely to me it might not be configured to handle proxying FTP requests. You might want to read [this](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-proxies#non-http-protocols-over-an-http-proxy) to make sure you understand what's happening : you've sent an HTTP request to a proxy which is supposed to ask it to get a resource over FTP and forward it to you over HTTP. The proxy answers with a blank response (invalid for HTTP) which lets me think it encounters an error

Comment: Ah still, you might want to try without the `-l` as it doesn't really make sense since you're sending HTTP requests (since you're using an HTTP proxy). If the flag is necessary then you might need to use proxy tunnelling as described in the doc I linked above, but that's something your proxy would have even less chance of supporting

Comment: Hello Aaron, Finally it worked. I guess the server side had a issue or not sure what fixed where. This is what I tried. curl -l -U serviceact:servicepwd -v --socks5 sftpproxy:port -k sftp://user:pwd@vendor.com:port/reports/

Comment: I see you've added `--socks5` to your command, would it still work if you removed it? If not, you've found the solution to your problem and should post it as an answer, it might be useful to future readers. It'd be best to be able to explain why it was needed (I have no idea myself), but even without that the answer might be useful